# Google Drive - Providing resource paths

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a Hangman game in HTML and JavaScript.

When I run this on my local machine, it works perfectly. What happens is that when the user loses the game then an image called `lose.png` is displayed. If the user wins then the image `win.png` is displayed.

Moreoever, other images that need to be displayed are displayed fine. But only the two images that need to be displayed at the end of the game are not displayed.

But when I uploaded this to Google Drive and then tried to play it from there, The other parts are completely fine but the last image change to `win.png` or `lose.png` does not take place.

The complete code is available here - [hangman](http://goo.gl/ZthTca).

The part of code that does not work is:

```
if(score === wordIs.length) {
    document.getElementById("respimg").setAttribute("src","img/win.png");
    alert("You won the game!!\nA new game has been started.");
    return true;
}
if(attrem <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("respimg").setAttribute("src","img/lose.png")
    alert("Your attempts are over.\nYou lost the game.\nThe word you were trying to guess was:\"" + wordIs + "\"");
    return true;
}
```

In the above code:

1. `attrem` is the number of attempts remaining
2. `wordIs` is the word to be guessed by the user

Note that the alert statements are working perfectly fine. But the image does not change when the file is run from Google Drive.

But when I run it on my local machine, then the image changes.

The HTML file can be viewed here - [Main](http://goo.gl/S2Yq0n)

This HTML file also uses the Twitter Bootstrap. But I don't think that ties in with the issue that I'm facing.

Comment: check image path, change it to relative

Comment: Open up JavaScript console in any web browser of your choice. Look for errors - it's obvious you haven't corrected the paths (i.e. URIs) of resources.

Comment: The path is relative. Please go through the code atleast.

Comment: The game works fine in IE 8 and Firefox (latest version). Try clearing your cache...

Comment: @bastos.sergio but not in Chrome

Comment: @IcyFlame as a test can you comment out the alert so just image changing code remains?

Answer (score 0):

Open up JavaScript console in any web browser of your choice. Look for errors - it's obvious you haven't corrected the paths (i.e. URIs) of resources.

This is where you find errors in Chrome console:

[image: Console]

---

This is the error - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://googledrive.com/host/0B7M-r5gOz6CVYmQwaGNkaC1xM1k/js/twitter-bootstrap-2.2.2/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: I did that. There is no error shown there. Please note that I have done fair bit of coding in JS, so you don't need to tell me basic things like this.